# Can a non devil fruit user use Haki with Seastone cuffs?

Tags: one-piece

This question is basically an extension of [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/53261/why-cant-haki-be-used-with-seastone-cuffs), in which it's mentioned that a devil fruit user can't use Haki because he/she gets weak due to seastone, but seastone shouldn't have any affect on Non-Devil fruit user.  So can they use Haki while they are in contact of seastone? Like Zoro and Ussop did during Water 7 arc.

Answer (score 2):

https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Silvers_Rayleigh is a good example! In his introduction, he does something like that already.

In the latest Wano arc, we see Luffy does something like Rayleigh(breaks seastone cuffs)

I agree to the point that https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/53266/53844, overtime people can build stamina to resist seastone cuffs and also seastone cuffs effect might vary unlike sea

Answer (score 1):

They can use it. Reason is seastone only nullifies devil fruit powers. Haki is a whole different kind of power.

For evidence you can look up **Wano Arc**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can. There isn't very direct proof though, but the much we have, it says, no dfs are fine and can use haki. Although I am not use about breaking them using haki... Seastones are very durable. Probably it required advanced haki to break them!!